# How can I make it so that python doesn't think that the eval function is a method

Tags: python, eval

I want to know how to be able to do something of this general kind

```
Import Module

Class MyObject:
    def __init__(self,string):  
        self.variable=Module.eval(string).method
```

Basically I am trying to write a function that can take a string as an input, but treat it like a variable, method, class, function etc.

Edit: what I don't want is the getattr function. That only return the value of the attribute, I need it to return a pointer to the attribute itself so that I can then edit it. A better code example of what I want is like this

```
Import Module

Class MyObject:
    def __init__(self,string):  
        self.eval(string)=Module.eval(string).method
```

Comment: This sounds like a complex way to solve a problem, but you haven't said what the problem is.  Can you elaborate what you will do with this?  There might be a simpler solution.

Comment: I want my program to be able to interface with a user, as such many commands will come in as strings, so I need to convert them to actual code, (without resorting to a bunch of conditionals). But I figured out what I wanted anyway, I wanted the setattr function

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want the `getattr` function.

```
self.variable = getattr(Module, string).method
```

`getattr` returns the attribute named by `string` from `Module`. Here's a concrete example:

```
import math
# Both expressions return the same object
s1 = math.sqrt
s2 = getattr(math, 'sqrt')
assert s1 is s2
```

To handle the assignment in your example, use `setattr`:

```
setattr(self, string, getattr(Module, string).method)
```

A concrete example:

```
class A(object):
   pass

A.x = 5
setattr(A, 'x', 3)
assert A.x == 3
```

Comment: I don't think the getattr function will do what I want it to do in this case

Comment: `setattr(self, string, getattr(Module, string).method)`, maybe, using the example from your question?